# What Marvel character has this 'W' symbol?

Tags: marvel, comics, character-identification, symbols

[image: baby in Marvel superheroes shirt]

My son got this shirt. It has six comics character's symbols on it; five of which I can identify:

```
Spider-Man Captain America  Iron Man
   Thor        (???)         Hulk
```

Wolverine seems like he'd fit the bill; that would pretty much round out Marvel's top 6 heroes, although he's not quite as Avengers-related as the other five. But, Wolverine is more of a yellow and black kind of guy, and I've never seen a symbol like that.

Whom does the 'W' symbol represent?

Note: 2-month old provided for scale.

Comment: Certainly not **Alan Walker**

Comment: Not being a sufficiently dedicated fan, my first thought was Wario (from Mario brothers, which I also haven’t followed well).

Comment: This is not an authorized shirt, hence the artwork being *intentionally* irregular.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I want to say the Wasp, because this shirt seems Avengers-themed and the Wasp was a founding member of the Avengers. For what it's worth, [this Wasp wallet](https://shop.buckle-down.com/products/marvel-now-bi-fold-wallet-retro-wasp-logo-wasp-ant-man-scene-blocks) has almost the same logo, and is apparently officially licensed:

> This product is handcrafted in the USA by Buckle-Down, Inc. and is Officially Licensed by Marvel Comics.

[image: Wasp wallet]

Comment: I agree it is likely the Wasp since you've found that exact symbol associated with her.  Her colors have at points matched, too, unlike Wolverine.  I will say all three of the suggested characters well predate Spider Man as Avengers.

Comment: This image is from the 1992 Marvel Handbook; https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BGGH.jpg

Comment: Grmbl. I'm finding panels of her wearing a W, such as [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgmJl.jpg), but no full logo yet.

Comment: @Jenayah - The logo is on her top. Imagine a cut-out circle.

Comment: @Valorum sure, but I wish I'd find an actual cut of it,you know like when they put logos in the top left corner of the cover sometimes. There's no doubt it's the Wasp though

Answer (score 41):

It represents an older symbol for [The Wasp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasp_(comics)#1960s), I'm pretty sure it's from an Avengers version, but the wiki page is pretty weak.  All I could come up with after 30 mins.

[image: Wasp symbol matching the one in the question]

[Example](https://www.zazzle.com/classic_wasp_icon_postcard-239508115034341048)

Answer (score 13):

Clearly the Wasp. Wonder Man would be the only other alternative in my opinion (one of my underutilized faves btw) however his isn't really close when examined comparatively.

[image: Comic panel showing Wasp with the logo on her chest]

Comment: I disagree that Wonder Man would be the only other alternative -- my first guess (I'm not very familiar with comics, but I like the movies) was _Widow_, for Black Widow. Still doesn't make that much sense, though. It's obviously the Wasp.

Comment: @only_pro It kind of should be Black Widow, assuming that shirt is inspired by the recent movies, since she's one of the core members of the Avengers as depicted by the MCU, and the Wasp is kind of a side-character.  (Though they also omitted Hawkeye in favor of Spiderman...)  As for Wonder Man, I doubt he'll ever get a movie since DC would complain that it infringes on Wonder Woman.

Comment: Black Widow's logo is a [red hourglass shape](https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/008/972/932/large/imaginative-hobbyist-blackwidowmovielogo.jpg?1516389036), often in a circle

Answer (score 8):

I'm assuming it is [Wonder Man](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Man).  Very close to this pic from Wikipedia.

[image: Wonder Man wearing his red W symbol on his chest]

Comment: The logo doesn't seem to be a very close match, at all. -1

Comment: From that article: "in 2012, Wonder Man was ranked 38th in IGN's list of 'The Top 50 Avengers'." ***There are over 50 Avengers?***

Comment: Yes, it's obviously Wonder Man. The logo it's identical, as it is the colours combination. It's a bit of a weird selection, too: he is not one of the most popular Marvel heroes, nor he's particularly affiliated with Spiderman.

Comment: @Stormblessed: hundreds. Basically almost every Marvel character has been, in a way or another, an Avenger.

Comment: @Stormblessed There are hundreds of heroes who have been Avengers at some point, especially if you count all the people who've been memebers under various hero names/powers.

Comment: @Stormblessed - Not counting the entire roster of East Coast Avengers, West Coast Avengers, Great Lakes Avengers, Alternate Universe and Ultimate versions, I'd be surprised if there weren't several hundred recognised Avengers.

Comment: @motoDrizzt no, the logo from the question is more likely from **The Wasp**: it has two insectoid eyes shapes below the W, and the middle cone of the letter W is only half the height of the W, as opposed to Wonder Man shirt design.

Comment: @motoDrizzt This just goes to show how many Avengers that there have been, that there are _two_ heroes with a red W on a black background.

Comment: @Stormblessed: There's an old Marvel "What if..?" about what would happen if every Avenger (present and former) showed up when Cap says "Avengers Assemble" and the whole city was flooded with superheroes! and I think it was too chaotic and the villains got away

Comment: I mean, if _this_ [Avengers Assemble](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSiWugMrz8w) counts, there are thousands... or hundreds of thousands, even.

Comment: @Valorum care to give this a go? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216940/how-many-avengers-are-there You did a great job with the Acme Looney Tunes question.

Comment: @TheAsh - Waaaaaaaay too broad for my liking.