# Which Marvel characters are represented on this t-shirt?

Tags: marvel, character-identification

[image: T-shirt with 12 icons portraying or representing Marvel characters]

1. Ant-Man
2. Vision
3. ????
4. Black Panther
5. ????
6. Thor
7. Hulk
8. Captain America
9. ????
10. ????
11. Spider-Man
12. Black Widow??

Comment: 5 is Iron Man I think

Answer (score 14):

1. Ant-Man
2. Vision
3. Looks to be the Eye of Agamotto probably representing Doctor Strange
4. Black Panther
5. Iron Man
6. Thor
7. Hulk
8. Captain America
9. Wasp as per [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/216800/58193)
10. I thought this was a Yaka Arrow so believed this to be Yondu but per the theming of the shirt it’s probably more likely representing Hawkeye
11. Spider-Man
12. Black Widow

Comment: I can't find #9 online. Best I could see is this; https://marvel.fandom.com/wiki/Trick_Arrows?file=Trick_Arrows_and_Hawkeye%2527s_Quiver.jpg but I'm guessing it's supposed to be a net or a putty arrow.

Comment: Definitely the Eye of Agamotto; https://static0.cbrimages.com/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/defenders-hulk-agamotto.jpg?q=50&fit=crop&w=740&h=374&dpr=1.5

Comment: It would be nice if that arrow was a design I could actually find for Hawkeye. https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/marveldatabase/images/a/ae/Trick_Arrows_and_Hawkeye%27s_Quiver.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20210307005746

Comment: #9 is the first/early logo of Wonderman (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Man)

Comment: #3 Maybe Uatu, The Watcher (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uatu)

Comment: @KenIngram I disagree that it's Wonder Man, the design more closely represents Wasp and matches other _known_ logos for her. Also I did think of Uatu there but given the other members, and that it matches the Eye of Agamotto, I doubt it.

Answer (score 5):

#3 Dr. Strange

#5 Iron Man

#9 Wasp (thanks TheLethalCarrot and LogicDictates)

#10 Maybe Hawkeye

#12 Yes :)

Comment: #9 is the Wasp. Her original costume had that symbol high on the chest.